# django StackedInline tinyMCE problem

Tags: django, tinymce

When I click `Add another {{ verbose_name }}` in inline block, displays tinymce-textatea, but all controls and edit are disabled ( no errors in console ). In 3 first textarea's tinymce works properly.
Imho it is init problem. 
Code:

```
#templates\admin\base.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% admin_media_prefix %}tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "{% filter escapejs %}{% admin_media_prefix %}{% endfilter %}";

    var tMCE = tinyMCE.init({
        //General otptions
        mode : 'textareas',
        theme: 'advanced',
        readonly : false,
        plugins : 'autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template',

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor',
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : 'cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,|,image,media,|,fullscreen,code',
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : '',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
            var w = window.open('/elfinder', null, 'width=1000,height=800');
            w.tinymceFileField = field_name;
            w.tinymceFileWin = win;
        }

    });
</script>

#admin.py
class PostInline( admin.TabularInline ):
    model = Post
    readonly_fields = ('created', 'updated')

class ItemAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    inlines = [
        PostInline,
    ]
    readonly_fields = ('created', 'updated')
```

**UPDATE:**

```
#base.html

$(document).ready(function(){     
    tinyMCE.settings = tinyMCE_opt;
    $( 'textarea:not(.inline-group textarea)' ).each( function() {
        tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceAddControl', false, this.id );
    } );
});
#stacked.html
$(rows).formset({
            prefix: "{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}",
            addText: "{% blocktrans with inline_admin_formset.opts.verbose_name|title as verbose_name %}Add another {{ verbose_name }}{% endblocktrans %}",
            formCssClass: "dynamic-{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}",
            deleteCssClass: "inline-deletelink",
            deleteText: "{% trans "Remove" %}",
            emptyCssClass: "empty-form",
            removed: updateInlineLabel,
            added: (function(row) {
                initPrepopulatedFields(row);
                reinitDateTimeShortCuts();
                updateSelectFilter();
                updateInlineLabel(row);

                $( row ).find( 'textarea' ).each( function() {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceAddControl', false, this.id );
                } );

            })
        });
```

But appears another problem: 
If an error occurred method `formset` does not work anymore and inlines textareas is a simple textareas

Comment: Sounds like for tinymce 4 the command becomes `tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, this.id);`, but I found their documentation on this hard to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution ( thanks [Thomas](/users/234254/thomas)):

```
#base.html
$(document).ready(function(){    
    tinyMCE.settings = tinyMCE_opt;
    $( 'textarea:not(.inline-group textarea)' ).each( function() {
        tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceAddControl', false, this.id );
    } );        
});

#stacked.html

$(rows).formset({
    prefix: "{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}",
    addText: "{% blocktrans with inline_admin_formset.opts.verbose_name|title as verbose_name %}Add another {{ verbose_name }}{% endblocktrans %}",
    formCssClass: "dynamic-{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}",
    deleteCssClass: "inline-deletelink",
    deleteText: "{% trans "
    Remove " %}",
    emptyCssClass: "empty-form",
    removed: updateInlineLabel,
    added: (function (row) {
        initPrepopulatedFields(row);
        reinitDateTimeShortCuts();
        updateSelectFilter();
        updateInlineLabel(row);
        $(row).find('textarea').each(function () {
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, this.id);
        });


    })
});

$('.dynamic-{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }} textarea').each(function () {
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, this.id);
});
```

Comment: problem: after click on close icon and click on Add another {{ verbose_name }} tinyMCE fails. solution: `removed: function(row) {
                updateInlineLabel(row);
                $( row ).find( 'textarea' ).each( function() {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceRemoveControl', false, this.id );
                });
            },`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you need to capture that "new inline" button press and use it to attach mce to the newly created fields yourself. or you could re-init the whole page but that would just be wasteful.

EDIT:

you need to use

```
django.jquery("#id-of-button").click(function () {
     tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl',false,'id-of-new-textarea');
}
```

Comment: >>o attach mce to the newly created fields. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack that works (at least on TinyMCE 3.x) without needing to modify the template.

```
django.jQuery(function ($) {  // django's copy of jQuery is crucial for old_add.click()
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.add-row a').each(function () {
            var inline_group = $(this).parents('.inline-group');
            var new_add = $(this).clone();
            var old_add = $(this);
            old_add.hide().before(new_add);
            new_add.click(function () {
                old_add.click();
                if (inline_group.find('.mceEditor').length) {
                    var widget = inline_group.find('.form-row:not(.empty-form) .mceEditor');
                    var textarea = widget.prev('textarea').show();
                    widget.remove();
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, textarea.attr('id'));
                }
            });
        });
    }, 0);
});
```